# Work on a column of a dataset

Tags: sas

I'm new in SAS. I have a dataset with some columns. There's a column called "Events" that contains some numbers. How can I divide the full column by a number for example 3?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a new variable whose value is one third of the value of an existing variable then just use an assignment statement in a data step.

So if you have a dataset named HAVE with a numeric variable named A your program to create a new dataset named WANT with the new variable named B would look like this.

```
data want;
  set have;
  b = a/3;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just get an answer, not a new variable you can use `proc sql`.

```
proc sql;
select sum(Events) / 3 from have;
quit;
```

Without the inclusion of a `group by` statement `proc sql` will sum over the entire column. If you had a column that contained variables like `Type-A`, `Type-B`, `Type-C`, etc you could change the code to something like:

```
proc sql;
select type, sum(Events) from have
group by type;
quit;
```

The code above would give you the sum of the `Events` column for each grouping and you could also divide by some number.